# Insert Json document with an image path value into a css background attribute

Tags: javascript, css, json, mongodb

I have a mongodb database with documents that have img values set up like this:

"img": "../folder/img.jpg"

is it possible to use this string in my css to change the background image? I need to do this because the image should change with other values in the json document.

Comment: something like this `background-image: url('../folder/img.jpg');` ?

Comment: I'm not "wrong", I was asking a question because I didn't understand what he was asking

Comment: @dylan are you using nodejs, express? or other tech?

Comment: @Pabs123, I didn't see it was a question. Any way he wants get image url paths from mongodb and create a dynamically styles  from it.

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes i am using nodejs

Comment: So, see my answer below. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you whish to know how to apply the background image in html when you retrieved the image string form mongodb:**

When you can't dynamicaly build your css you can apply this to your html element when building your html page:

```
<!-- Element which needs a dynamic background image, for example a div -->
<div style="background-image: url('../folder/img.jpg');">
<div>
```

If you can dynamically build your css file or your style tag you can do this

**css**

```
#myelement{
   background-image: url('../folder/img.jpg');
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="myelement">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer man but this doesn't really pertain to my question

Answer (score 1):

Create a route which serves a dynamic css:

> example.com/myuser/mycss/1

And you create a logic to return your css depending on data from mongodb:

```
function mycss(req, res) {
    MyImgs..find({
       where: {
         _id: req.params.id
       }
    }).then(function(singleDoc){
          var cssContent = ' #myimg {background-image: url('+singleDoc.img+'); }';

          res.contentType('text/css');
          return res.end(cssContent);
    });
}
```

**Note this a controller action example using nodejs / express.**

On your head tag you can add something like that:

```
<head>
   <link type="text/css" src="example.com/myuser/mycss/1" />
</head>
```